# Exporting clashes matrix and results out of BIM 360 Model Coordination to Excel

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

How can I export the clashes out of BIM 360 Model Coordination to Excel like we export Clash Report in Navisworks?

Answer (score 0):

With Model Coordination API, you can extract the raw clash data. This tutorial tells more:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/model-coordination/mc-tutorial-clash/
As to export to Excel you will need to use API of Excel to write the sheet yourself. They have library server side or client side.
In some of our Forge samples, we demo the usage of Excel with other Forge API (such as Model Derivative). The logic could be similar when exporting clash data.

server side lib: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-bim360.asset.exchange.excel
client side lib: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-javascript-extract.spreadsheet

In addition, we also have one sample that exports clash data to PDF.
https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-bim360-clashpdfexport

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the raw count of clashes between models without any information about the clash itself (like the matrix from BIM 360 shows), you can use the "Inspect" tool in Chrome. After opening the tool, navigate to the "Network" tab and then open up the page that shows the clash matrix. It will give you a list of items and a visual that shows when they downloaded. Above the visual, there should be a box with the word "Filter" in it. Type "matrix".

Two files should appear. Click on the one that is a bigger file. A display should open giving you the raw data of the matrix. You can select it all and copy and paste it where you want it.